# Still seeing SQS usage for queue with Lambda function but have not used it this month

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda and the trigger for the lambda is an SQS queue. I have not run it at all this month but I am still seeing usage for SQS is this something that is correct behaviour or is there something else using SQS I need to look into.

Comment: SQS offers 1 million requests free every month in its free tier. If you exceed the number of requests, then you'll be charged. Please have a detailed look at your billing dashboard to have some clarity.

Comment: Can you give us some more context? Where does SQS get its data from?

Comment: When your lambda throws an exception the message is requeued.And the your lambda will after a while triggered again.  You can looked at the message in the queue with AWS console. There you can also delete this messages, or you make a new version of yourr lambda which can worked on the messages without an exception

Comment: Maybe you could provide the cloudwatch logs, if there are any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Lambda service **polls** the Amazon SQS queue for any messages that are available. If messages are returned, then the Lambda service *invokes* the appropriate AWS Lambda function.

Thus, if there is a Lambda function configured to trigger from a queue, then **the Lambda service will continue to poll that queue even if there are no messages available**. (I *presume* that is uses Long Polling to reduce the number of calls.)

Thus, you are probably seeing the charges related to the attempts to retrieve messages from the queue.